# NuGet package already added in Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, geolocation, nuget

I'm working on Xamarin.Forms project, and after installing James Montemagno's Geolocator Plugin for Xamarin and Windows named `Xam.Plugin.Geolocator` I got an error like this in Android project:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
already added : 
Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;
```

What does it mean and how to solve this?

Comment: What version of GeoLocator did you install? And what version of AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat do you have installed? You can check by right-clicking your Android project and clicking "Manage Nuget packages"

Comment: You are most likely mixing Android Support versions between Xamarin.Forms and Xam.Plugin.Geolocator. Can you please share a list of the packages installed in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was thrown because I referenced `Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.25.4.0.2` in my .Droid project. It had nothing to do with `Xam.Plugin.Geolocator`. Thanks to @sme and @Jon Douglas for helpful comments.

I managed to solve the error by updating the `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.23.3.0` to version `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.25.4.0.2`.